# Can't launch ClickHouse. Exit code 203

Tags: clickhouse

I tried a lot but CH did not work. Please help me/

I installen ClickHouse on CentOs7 according to the  https://clickhouse.tech/docs/ru/getting-started/install/
I entered

```
sudo systemctl status  clickhouse-server
```

and did not see any result

I entered `sudo clickhouse-client -h 127.0.0.1 --user default`

> sudo: unable to execute /bin/clickhouse-client: Operation not permitted

I entered `sudo systemctl status  clickhouse-server`

```
clickhouse-server.service - ClickHouse Server (analytic DBMS for big data)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-12-24 18:56:34 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 7871 ExecStart=/usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --pid-file=/run/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.pid (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 7871 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   CGroup: /machine.slice/libpod-5371acee9c1a12529197f3a6dadcbd14393f20d7e91c2e347e9147508002aee7.scope/system.slice/clickhouse-server.service

Dec 24 18:56:34 ok-parser systemd[1]: Unit clickhouse-server.service entered failed state.
```

Log file **/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log** is empty

Comment: Check the log: */var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log*. Look at Centos related questions/answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclickhouse%5D+centos

Comment: Log file /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log is empty

Comment: could you run *sudo systemctl status clickhouse-server.service --no-pager --full* to get more info?

Comment: disable SELinux (at least temporary). Check that files /usr/bin/clickhouse-server  & /usr/bin/clickhouse exist and have executable flags

Answer (score 4):

I have faced a very similar or exactly the same issue recently.

It seems to be a ClickHouse issue: [ClickHouse server fails to start after upgrading from `22.3.6.5-lts` to `22.4.5.9-stable` · Issue #37099 · ClickHouse/ClickHouse](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/37099).

Here is the [solution comment](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/37099#issuecomment-1125315887):

> **[den-crane](https://github.com/den-crane)** commented [May 12, 2022, 9:48 PM GMT+3](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/37099#issuecomment-1125315887)
>
> [@svbrunov](https://github.com/svbrunov) you need to do
>
> ```
> rm /etc/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service
> systemctl daemon-reload
> service clickhouse-server restart
> ```